# combining two select queries from the same table

Tags: mysql

I need to do something like this:

```
id  tag  status user   trial   Value (other columns)... 
1   A    Pass   peter  first   0
2   A    Pass   peter  second  1
3   A    Fail   peter  third   3
4   B    Pass   peter  first   4
5   B    Pass   peter  second  5
6   B    Pass   peter  third   6
```

select the rows that tag equal A and status equal to Pass  and find the same  value for other tag ex:B

```
id  tag  status user   trial   Value_tag_A  Value_tag_B  (other columns)... 
1   A    Pass   peter  first   O            4
2   A    Pass   peter  second  1            5
```

I can do some processing using php to get this result, but i'm wondering if i can do it directly using sql

I've tried numerous variations and can't seem to get close  to the result.

Solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9068d/17

Comment: This seems quite straightforward. What did you try? And see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: (1) what have you tried, (2) _a hint_, you can `join` tables to themselves so long as each reference is aliased.

Comment: I mis read the question and did not see additional columns (Value_tag_A  Value_tag_B). A subquery to itself will do it.

Comment: @anonyXmous A subquery would be quite unnecessary. What else could we try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why in the rows where `tag=A` also have `Value_tag_B`. I will ignore this and maybe the following query is an approach.

```
SELECT DISTINCT y.status, y.`user`, y.trial, 
(SELECT Value FROM toto WHERE y.`user` = `user` and y.trial = trial and tag = 'A' ) AS Value_tag_A,
(SELECT Value FROM toto WHERE y.`user` = `user` and y.trial = trial and tag = 'B' ) AS Value_tag_B
FROM toto y
WHERE y.trial NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT trial FROM toto WHERE `status` <> 'Pass')
```

The code has been modified.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9068d/13)

Comment: your code is returning also the row  `3   A    Fail   peter  third   3`
 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9068d/1

Comment: @aachraf Thank you for correcting me and providing the data. Perhaps you don't want `trail=3` since Peter failures when `tag=A`.

Comment: thank you Song,actually, i found exactly what I want, but my code is different from yours : 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9068d/17

Comment: Thank you@aachraf